# How to move Symfony2 application from localhost to deployment server (LAMP CentOS)

Tags: php, symfony, centos, lamp

I have developed a Symfony2 app on my local machine. I access it using PHP's built-in server, via `http://localhost:8000/`

Question: how do I move this application to my VPS (LAMP CentOS) so that it can be accessed like this:

```
http://example.com
```

and is it any different for installing it on:

```
http://subdomain.example.com
```

PLEASE if by any chance you can provide a step by step instructions, it will be much appreciated and I'm sure useful to many others too. I'm used to working with stuff where you can simply move files from one place to another, update some config data and it works (Wordpress, coding without frameworks etc.)

Comment: do you need more help / informations ?

Comment: Thanks for asking, actually I do. Because now I also need to learn git, so I haven't been able to implement neither of the answers so far. My development machine is WAMP if it makes any difference. I also tried using Capifony, but didn't even manage to install Ruby, I get the "No package rubygems available." or "No package ruby available." So I guess I need additional steps that would really make this dummy-proof (which command I run where etc.)   Tried asking for help on #symfony IRC channel and just been ignored.

Comment: A good way to start a git versionning of Symfony is to create an account on bitbucket.org (it's free and your project can be private ) . Since bitbucket is based on a symfony project, there is a tutorial on how git your project online :) . if you need specific tips on git comment , leave a comment here , and we ll start a chat

Comment: a git tutorial from symfony official documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to me is to have your project in  a versionning system like git or svn without the vendors dir of course ...

This way, your simply have to do :

```
1) git clone your project into the prod dir

2) php composer.phar install to install your vendors

2b) create the mysql user with correct login and password according to your parameters.yml

 3) php app/console doctrine:database:create to create your database with the credentials you set up in mysql

 4) php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force to perform the database tables creation
 5) testing the project :)
```

If you are not using a versionning system just upload your project to your server with an ftp software without the vendors directory ( it will be feeded by step 2) then perform 3rd , 4th and 5th steps !

For the subdomain part of your request you have to creats a subdomain folder on your server ( by using plesk if you have it ) or by manually creating a vhost config to specify the sub domain path. I can t provide you an example right now ( i m writing this from my mobile device and i don t have clear step by step procedure in order to achieve this )

Answer (score 1):

*[Install your environment]*

So, First you need to [install](https://library.linode.com/lamp-guides/centos-6#sph_install-and-configure-the-apache-web-server) and run an apache Server. Find [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html) the [minimum basics to get your application running under Apache2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html). Then make sure you've PHP5 and MySQL  up and running. Otherwise check,

- [Install and Configure MySQL Database Server](https://library.linode.com/lamp-guides/centos-6#sph_id6)
- [Installing and Configuring PHP](https://library.linode.com/lamp-guides/centos-6#sph_installing-and-configuring-php)

---

*[Deploy your application]*

> Deploying can be a complex and varied task depending on your setup and
>   needs - *Symfony.com*

It's then up to you to choose the right way to deploy your application, you can do it,

- [Using Basic File Transfer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html#basic-file-transfer)
- [Using Source Control](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html#using-source-control)
- [Using Build scripts](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html#using-build-scripts-and-other-tools)

I would recommend using [Capifony](http://capifony.org) which was build on top of Capistrano to adapt it to Symfony applications.

---

*[Post-Deployment Tasks]*

Your deployment process should be tailored to guarantee that all the required post-deployment tasks (Like [updating your dependencies](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html#b-update-your-vendors), [setting your application configuration files](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html#a-configure-your-app-config-parameters-yml-file), [clearing the cache](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html#c-clear-your-symfony-cache) and [dumping your assets](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html#d-dump-your-assetic-assets), [etc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html#e-other-things)) are executed.

To get the big picture, read the [How to deploy a Symfony2 application](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html) of the [Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/index.html).